# Back button in an Activity without recreate previous Activity (Android)

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a master activity that is a menu (A). The activity A have 6 fragments. One of them is a gallery of pictures (Figure 1). When you touch a picture you go to the picture details activity (B) (Figure 2). I add the tag "parentName" to the activity B in the AndroidManifest.xml. So the parent of the activity B is the activity A. The problem is: when you are in activity B and you press the Up Button (Figure 2) the activity A is recreated and it shows the first fragment of the activity A (not the gallery fragment). I want the same behavior of the Instragram app when you back to a previous activity. It seems like the Instagram app don't recreate the previous activity. The expected behavior is also similar to the behavior of the back button (Figure 3). How can I achieve this behavior? Thanks

[image: Figure 1. Master Activity with Gallery fragment]
**Figure 1. Picture details Activity**

[image: Figure 2. Picture details Activity]
**Figure 2. Picture details Activity**

[image: Figure 3. Back button]
**Figure 3. Back button**

Comment: you are working with fragment or only activities?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've solved my problem easily. I just had to add the tag **android:launchMode="singleTop"** to the activity A. I also add the next code in the activity A but probably isn't necessary. I hope you find it useful.

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
{
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be programatically you are using this :

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new FragmentB(),null).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Replace it with this line :

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.content_frame, fragment,null).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Comment: I can't use that because I'm changing to activity B using Intents