# Activity recreate itself when press back button

Tags: android, android-activity, recreate

I have 2 activities.

- ActivityA : i use ImagePickerActivity from [poly-picker](https://github.com/jaydeepw/poly-picker) library to select multi files and send paths to ActivityB
- ActivityB : each file, i create one view and add to relative layout programmatically.

But my problem is when i press back button, ActivityB not finish, it recreate itself. number of recreate times is equal to number of files.

Pls, help, thanks and sorry about English.

Comment: could you show your code in both of activities ?

Comment: This link could be useful, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26434896/back-button-in-an-activity-without-recreate-previous-activity-android

Answer (score 0):

When you press the back button, the Activity gets destroyed. So, when the activity is started again, it recreates itself.

Comment: i see, but i want back to ActivityA from ActivityB when i press back button on ActivityB. But it does not, it recreate ActivityB

Answer (score 0):

Override onBackPressed() in ActivityB

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    ActivityB.this.finish();
}
```